# Remove Ruby Installation to switch to RVM installations on MAC OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, uninstallation

I wanted to start developing RoR on my Macbook (did it on Windows mostly).

So i read some tutorials and ran into Homebrew. Tried it.
This installed me ruby version 2.0.0p0.

Later on I found RVM packages, udpated my XCode nad command line tools and made RVM running.
There I installed ruby 1.9.3 which I am currently using.

Later on I had some trouble to setup right profile ( ~/.profile needed to be updated as well, package does it on ~/.bash_profile).

So now I have ruby 1.8.7 original, version 2.0.0 installed by HomeBrew and ruby 1.9.3 installed by RVM.

But RVM can only switch between ruby versions that are managed by it.

So how do I safely remove 1.8.7, 2.0.0 and HomeBrew without damaging the RVM packages? I don't want to just delete the folders or can I?
After removal I want to install the versions again with RVM to be able to switch between the versions easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not under any circumstances mess with 1.8.7 original.

Nor do I entirely understand why you want to remove Homebrew. You can, but why? Just ignore it.

If you want to use RVM (I certainly do not, I much prefer `rbenv`, but everyone to his own taste), then just go ahead and have RVM install its own copies of the other versions of Ruby.

Comment: I used brew to uninstall 2.0.0 and installed other versions by rvm, didn't touch the original package. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I found this too late. I'd already manually removed my 1.8 gem and am now struggling to get it all re-installed.

Comment: I have rbenv installed, when I execute ruby -v I can see that I have ruby 1.8.7, but according to rbenv the ruby version used is 2.0.0, so when I try to install rails it says: "RROR:  Error installing rails:
 activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3."

Comment: @p1nox If you are executing ruby -v and it says 1.8.7, but rbenv says 2.0.0, then you do *not* have rbenv installed (correctly). If rbenv is installed correctly, and rbenv says that the global ruby version is 2.0.0, then ruby -v in the Terminal will also say 2.0.0 (and "gem" will be the gem in the 2.0.0. library, and rails will be installed for that version, etc.)